# Why can't kernel modules print to the screen?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

I just read that Linux kernel modules can't print to the screen i.e. `printf` won't work. Does it have something to do with interrupt handling or why is that the case?

I have a memory studying some C and assembly which you couldn't use `printf` with and that was because interrupts were off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the kernel, `printf` doesn’t work because it’s not implemented! You use [`printk`](http://kernelbook.sourceforge.net/kernel-hacking.html/common-routines.html) instead (or `early_printk` in very early code, before the console is set up). `printk` is coded very carefully so that’s it’s safe to call from anywhere, in any circumstances (in particular, it doesn’t need to allocate memory). It implements pretty much the same API as `printf`, with the addition of a log level to indicate the importance of the message being printed, and format specifiers which are [useful in the kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/printk-formats.txt).